# How to grab .// with regex python?

Tags: python, regex

Why does this not work? In the regex finder, it matches. I'm trying to grab `.//` in strings

```
pat = '[\.\/]+(?!(docx|doc|pdf))'
bad = re.compile(pat)
bad.findall(tails[1])

print tails[1]
".//2005 Neuropathophys.doc"
```

This pattern seems to work on the regex matcher website http://regex101.com/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your regex would be the below to match `.//` which is not followed by `docx` or `doc` or `pdf`,

```
\.//(?!docx|doc|pdf)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oF0oW5)

Comment: I wanted to use [] so I could remove any matching set of punctuation symbols

Comment: is you use `.` inside character class, it matches a single dot anywhere in your string. See http://regex101.com/r/iN3tH8

Comment: `[\.\/]+` it means a dot or `/` symbol one or more times. So it matches `..`,`//`,`./`,`/.`

Answer (score 0):

In this case I think you don't need `\` in the `[]`. I think `\` is used just as escape character. But you don't need to use `\` in `[]` in Python regex. Because characters are automatically escaped in the `[]`.

So use regexp `[./]+` instead of `[\.\/]+`.

**sample:**

```
>>> import re
>>> s = ".//2005 Neuropathophys.doc"
>>> re.match("[./]+", s).group()
'.//'
```

Comment: Thanks! However, how do I make sure I don't get a match for . in .doc?

Comment: @user3314418 Use `\.+[/]+` to only match things like `.//` or `...////` etc.